# jQuery prop("disabled") is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, but none of the solutions work for this example, even though I know they should. Perhaps other pairs of eyes will help resolve this.

I have placed alerts before and after the code that sets the disabled property, which is indeed set correctly, but the element remains disabled.

I have excerpted the code necessary to reproduce this issue: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3977gy7/6/)

Here's some code just to satisfy the SO rule.

```
$(function () {
    var dbVendor = $("#database-vendor");
    $("#uses-db").on("change", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dbVendor.prop("disabled", ($(this).val() == "Yes" ? false : true));
    });
});
```

Comment: Javascript is function scope not block scope you need to pass that variable in

Comment: @Space ???????? Isn't that variable in the outer scope of the event handler function?

Comment: Sorry didn't see there was a fiddler attached

Comment: Stackoverflow has a snippets feature. There is no need to use an external site to host live demos at all now.

Comment: Unrelated, but that could just be `dbVendor.prop("disabled", $(this).val() != "Yes")` :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r3977gy7/21/ -> This might work for you,

Comment: it's conflicting with jQuery mobile... if you only use pure jQuery your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/r3977gy7/26/

Comment: @wlin That defeats the purpose though. The purpose is to use jQuery Mobile. You just have to use the jQuery Mobile API to enable the `selectmenu`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this solution, please

```
$(function () {
   var dbVendor = $("#database-vendor");
   $("#uses-db").on("change", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dbVendor.selectmenu($(this).val() === 'Yes' ? 'enable' : 'disable');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I struggled with this for hours.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with prop("disabled"), do

```
$dbVendor.selectmenu("enable");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3977gy7/30/

Documentation

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-enable

Comment: FYI, the variable is `dbVendor` not `$dbVendor`. +1 though, this answer is the only one that correctly uses the jQuery Mobile API.

Comment: Sorry, I changed dbVendor to $dbVendor in my jsFiddle.

Comment: dbVendor.selectmenu(($(this).val() == "Yes" ? "enable" : "disable")) is the shorter version.

Comment: I saw @andalm solution before yours, so +1 for your effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbVendor.selectmenu(($(this).val() == "Yes" ? "enable" : "disable"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using jquery mobile wich adds "ui-disabled" class to the element and his parent

```
$(function () {
   $("#uses-db").on("change", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if($(this).val() == "Yes"){
         $("#database-vendor").parent().removeClass("ui-disabled");
         $("#database-vendor").removeClass("ui-disabled");
         $("#database-vendor").removeAttr("disabled");//edited
      }
      else{
        $("#database-vendor").parent().addClass("ui-disabled");
        $("#database-vendor").addClass("ui-disabled")
        $("#database-vendor").addAttr("disabled");//edited
      }
   });
});
```

actually working code [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrielUVD/megc5p1t/1/)

Comment: Although this "works",  it is hacking into selectmenu plugin. Better to just do $("#database-vendor").selectmenu("enable") or ("disable").

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but try opening the select list on your fiddle.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrielUVD/megc5p1t/) just added $("database-vendor").removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score -2):

`#database-vendor` has been wrapped, by jQuery Mobile, with a div and a pile of JavaScript. Changing the disabled property of the select isn't causing jQuery Mobile to respond and change its div.

Removing jQuery Mobile will make the code work.

If you want it to work with jQuery Mobile, then you'll need to look at the jQuery Mobile API to figure out how to enable its pseudo-select elements.

Comment: Hmm, when I inspect the fiddle-output I get this: <select id="database-vendor" name="database-vendor" class="mobile-selectmenu-disabled ui-state-disabled" aria-disabled="true">... So there is a select hidden in the divs :)